# Why would window.top.location not take you out of an iFrame?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've Googled and looked over all StackOverflow questions and can't seem to find anything like this. I've got the following code here that takes a user out of the login modal and onto their homepage. Problem is, it doesn't seem to break through the modal, even though everywhere I look says window.top.location should do that. The page redirects successfully (meaning it goes to the right URL), but it redirects in the iFrame only.

```
echo "<script>window.top.location = '/group/$home';</script>";
```

Is there something else I should/could be doing to break out of the modal? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: are u sing iframe? And u want to redirect the  parent window from iframe ?

Comment: @michaelrmcneill have you tried `window.parent.location`..

Comment: @sAnS yes, I have and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

use `parent`

```
echo "<script>window.parent.location = '/group/$home';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you set the parent of the frame to the location of the any url and code must be executed from the iframe
     `top.location = url;`